# How to use variables in a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a class Database.php:

```
class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $dbUsername;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $connection;
    private $iv;
    public function __construct($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $iv)
    {
        $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
        $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->iv = $iv;

    }

    public function createDatabase($dbName){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
        $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbName";
        if(!$this->connection){
            var_dump("Connection failed");
        }
        else {
            $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute();
        }
        $this->connection->close();
    }

    public function createTable($query, $dbName){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $dbName);
        if(!$this->connection){
            var_dump("Connection failed");
        }
        else {
            $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute();
        }
        $this->connection->close();
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function executeQuery($dbname, $query){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $dbname);
        if(!$this->connection){
            var_dump("Connection failed");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute();
            $this->connection->close();
            return true;
        }

    }

    public function deleteFromTable($dbname, $query){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $dbname);
        if(!$this->connection){
            var_dump("Connection failed");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute();
            $this->connection->close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function check($query){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, "portal");;
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();
        if($statement->num_rows != 0){
            $this->connection->close();
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            $this->connection->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getId($username){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, 'portal');
        $id = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'"));
        $this->connection->close();
        return $id[0][0];
    }

    public function getData($query, $name = null){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, 'portal');
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $data = $statement->get_result()->fetch_array();
        if($name != null) {
            return $data[$name];
        }
        else{
            return $data;
        }
    }

    public function getDataAsArray($myQuery){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, 'portal');
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $myQuery);
        $results = array();
        while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $results[] = $line;
        }
        return $results;
    }

    public function encryptSSL($data){
        $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
        $secretHash = "";
        $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($data, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $this->iv);
        return $encryptedMessage . '||' . $this->iv;
    }
    public function decryptSSL($data, $iv){
        $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
        $secretHash = "";
        $decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt($data, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0,  $iv);
        return $decryptedMessage;
    }

}
```

And I'm using it as the following in my code to select, update, delete entries from the Database:

```
$customerInfo = $database->getData("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='$id'");

$database->executeQuery('portal', "INSERT into messages (userId, message, customerId, messageRead, messageTrash, messageDeleted, time_added, subject) VALUES(
                                                            '$id', '$message', '$customerId', 0, 0, 0, '$time_date', '$messageSubject')");
```

But as many probally know this is not safe for SQL injection. Binding parameters like `:ID` is a possiblity but I don't know how I can do this within a class. What if I want to have one function but multiple different querys for example: one query with one variable or one query with multiple variables like the above two queries

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Pass a parameter to the function with the variables you wish to use. `$db->query($sql, $variables);`.

Comment: @Script47 yes but what if some query has one variable and others multiple variables

Comment: You pass an array of variables.  `$db->query($sql, [$var1, $var2, $var3]);`.

Comment: @Script47 how can I bind them to the query?

Comment: Using some form of a loop I'd assume and run bind depending on the type of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to use variables directly in your queries without first escaping/treating them. But if you do, use php's 'bif' mysqli_real_escape_string($var) to escape them.

In your code you can do something like:

```
$customerInfo = $database->getData(sprintf("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='%d'", mysqli_real_escape_string($id)));

$database->executeQuery('portal', sprintf("INSERT into messages (userId, message, customerId, messageRead, messageTrash, messageDeleted, time_added, subject) VALUES('%d', '%s', '%s', 0, 0, 0, '%s', '%s')", mysqli_real_escape_string($id), mysqli_real_escape_string($message), mysqli_real_escape_string($customerId), mysqli_real_escape_string($time_date), mysqli_real_escape_string($messageSubject)));
```

Here's another way of doing it using strtr:

```
$placeholders = array(
  ':id' => mysqli_real_escape_string($id),
  ':message' => mysqli_real_escape_string($message),
  ':customerId' => mysqli_real_escape_string($customerId),
  ':time_date' => mysqli_real_escape_string($time_date),
  ':messageSubject' => mysqli_real_escape_string($messageSubject),
);

$database->executeQuery('portal', strtr("INSERT into messages (userId, message, customerId, messageRead, messageTrash, messageDeleted, time_added, subject) VALUES(':id', ':message', ':customerId', 0, 0, 0, ':time_date', ':messageSubject')", $placeholders));
```

Comment: This completely misses the OP's point... They wish to use parameters for their place holders for prepared statements.

Comment: With respect to using placeholders there's no straight forward way of doing it without using/writing some abstraction function to handle it(PDO). A handy php library will be sprintf.

Comment: You can do it quite simply, pass an array of parameters (in order of query requirements) loop through them and bind, it literally is as simple as that. Regardless of whether you feel that it is straight forward or not, you should at least answer the question with the OP's requirements in mind, not completely differently.

Comment: You don't need a loop for this.